# Integrating Wordpress from one WP site into another non WP site

Tags: wordpress, integration

I am developing a mobile version of a current WP site, but this mobile version is not WP.  So I need to be able to access the information in the database of the non-responsive, existing WP site in this new one.  The mobile site is located in a sub-folder called mobile (somesite.com/mobile) in the root directory of the current WP site.

I've visited the WP forum and posted this same question without responses. I've also read their integration page (http://codex.wordpress.org/Integrating_WordPress_with_Your_Website) but it doesn't seem like that would work for this application, because I figure it would just cause the mobile index.php page in the /mobile folder to just revert to the main theme.

Any suggestions or advice would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You should use the integration guide you posted:

```
define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);
```

This part tells wordpress not to use themes.

I think a better approach to this problem is to make the current wordpress theme responsive:
there are a number of ways to achieve this: you can add separate stylesheets for different browser sizes: http://css-tricks.com/resolution-specific-stylesheets/ or you can use css3 media queries directly in the stylesheet: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries

Answer (score 0):

You must create the new site using data from the WP site.

Ok. You will need to create your html/php files, but, using WP database.

You can just access WP database and query it... but you will have a lot of work, in some places... like, URL, you will need to transcript URLs saved on database, and, when a user click on that link, you will need treat it to find "back" what URL it means, to catch the content.

I't not a easy job.

The WP_Query (http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) class can easy your life.
The WP_Db (http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb) too.
Both, I think you can use without the whole WP.

---

But, like @Jonathan said, build a responsive template will be a best solution.